# Issue with reordering columns using fct_reorder

Tags: r, forcats

This code displays a bar chart but the columns are not in order. For what it is worth, I've tried it another way and have the same issue (no error, columns not in order by Revenue).

Three column bar chart, X-axis is Department, Y-axis is Revenue, Departments are Kabobs, Sides and Entrees, the shortest is in the center.

[image]

```
mod4 %>%
  mutate(name = fct_reorder(Department, Revenue)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(Department), y=Revenue))+
  geom_col(aes(fill=Department))+
  labs(title = "Bar Chart - Revenue by Department")
```

Comment: You applied the `fct_reorder()` to a new variable ("name") which is then not used in your ggplot2 call.

Comment: Sigh. Total newb here.

Comment: I can assure you that we've all been there.